# How to get rid of this error(array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given) in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, push-notification

I use the libraray Edujugon\PushNotification for push Notification but it give me the error.

> array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Please help me Here is my code. I do not know where i make a mistake. thanks in advance

```
public function likeActivity(Activity $activity)
{
    $authUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser();

    $authUser->likeActivity($activity);

    if ($activity->user_id != $authUser->id) {
        $user = User::where('id', $activity->user_id)->first();

        $push = new PushNotification('apn');
        $push->setMessage([
            'aps' => [
                'alert' => $authUser->name.' like your "'.$activity->activity_type.'"'.$activity->activity_title,
                'sound' => 'default',
                'badge' =>  $user->unreadNotifications->count()

            ],
            'extraPayLoad' => [
                // 'user' => $authUser,
                // 'post' => $post->id,
                'notification_type' => "Like Your Activity",
            ]
        ]);
        $push->setDevicesToken($user->deviceToken);
        $push->send();
        $feedback = $push->getFeedback();

        $user->notify(new LikedTheActivity($authUser, $activity));
    }

    return response()->json(['user'=> $authUser], 200);
}
```

Comment: Provide code for `$push->send()` and `$push->getFeedback()` function, also doesn't it say on which line the error happened?

Comment: In folder vendor/edujugon/push-notification/src/PushService.php on line 70 @Learner

Comment: i can use same code in other project it worked no need to provide code for $push->send() and $ush->getFeedback().

Comment: provide the code of the file `vendor/edujugon/push-notification/src/PushService.php`  if you want us to debug it...and also mention which is line 70